# Deleting credit note allocation to Invoice in Xero

Tags: php, xero-api

I have been working with the Xero API for some time but have not found a solution to my problem.

As per the API, payments to invoices can be removed by using the following documentation http://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments/, which I have working successfully. When it comes to credit note allocation however I cannot figure out if they can also be removed using the API. The API states that "credit note refunds" can be done using the payment API, but that is not the same as "removing" or "reversing" a payment allocation.

Once a credit note is created you can allocate an amount to an invoice. You can manually remove the allocation by logging in to Xero but as of yet I have not found a way of doing this via the API.

I have contacted Xero but haven't heard back yet. I am hoping someone either has a suggestion or it simply cannot be done via the API.

Answer (score 2):

A response from Xero to my question: *Unfortunately you cannot unallocate credit notes via API yet.* If you wish to vote for this to be added to the API then you can go to this link and vote: http://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/3628681-void-payments-and-credit-notes-via-api